# Openstack:Single node installation using cloudgear in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gmail, openstack-horizon

I'm trying to install openstack in cloudgear, after completing all steps I get installation successful login into Horizon locahost username:admin password:secret
After that  in browser when i try to give localhost username and password as described above
Now ,I have a problem running of dashboard in browser 
 [Image  i get error which comes in snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

what is the error you are getting? Check whether you have all the files inside /opt/stack/horizon directory some time cloning via git will b problem.

Comment: Internal server error  .                                                               Server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.                                                             Please contact server administrator,webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occured .more information about this error availlable at server log..

Comment: Are you running inside VM, what is the network you have NAT or Bridge? Did you check your horizon folder is it cloned properly. try to clean and rerun it using this local.conf file http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html

Comment: For more answers ask this question in ask.openstack.org